# Reading Pandas with tkinter at interval

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, tkinter

I have text file which i am reading as csv through pandas and i want to show the data in tkinter for that i am using Entry ,my csv file contain around 400 rows but i want to show only first 40th rows at first screen then after pressing next button next 41th to 81th rows should appear on screen and so on ....

**How to do iteration of rows at 40 rows at one time  in pandas ?
Is there any other best way to show text file in tkinter ?
Basically i want a dropdown option on DATE_TIME so that whenever user select 00 hours then only 00 hours data shown on screen , when user select 01 hours then only the 01 hrs data is shown on current screen .
I want a Exit button as well on my second windows 
TIA.**

```
Sample Data
Name:   Longitude(degree)   Latitude(degree)    DATE_TIME   Mean Sea Value (m)  DRY or WET
SD      87.0308            21.4441    00:00 IST 05-08-2019    -0.0467     DRY
Sea1    87.0544            21.4152    00:00 IST 05-08-2019    -1.0653     DRY
4K      86.9927            21.4197    00:00 IST 05-08-2019    -0.1331     DRY
4KP1    86.9960            21.4166    00:00 IST 05-08-2019    -0.0863     DRY
Name:   Longitude(degree)   Latitude(degree)    DATE_TIME   Mean Sea Value (m)  DRY or WET
SD      87.0308          21.4441      01:00 IST 05-08-2019    -0.0329     DRY
Sea1    87.0544          21.4152      01:00 IST 05-08-2019    -0.4067     DRY
4K      86.9927          21.4197      01:00 IST 05-08-2019    -0.0897     DRY
4KP1    86.9960           21.4166     01:00 IST 05-08-2019    -0.0676     DRY
```

code written

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

root=Tk()
root.geometry('150x150')
root.wm_title("WALPS_PROJECT")
root.iconbitmap("images/icon.ico")

Frame1=Frame(root,bd=5)
Frame1.pack(side=BOTTOM)

# bottomframe=Frame(root)
# bottomframe.pack(side='bottom')
# df=pd.read_csv("p_1_data.txt",sep="\t")
# row,column=df.shape
def showdata():
    top=Toplevel()
    df = pd.read_csv("p_1_data.txt", sep="\t",header=None)
    row, column = df.shape
    top.title("---DATA WINDOWS---")
    top.iconbitmap("images/icon.ico")
    for r in range(40):
        for c in range(column):
            e1=Entry(top)
            e1.insert(1,df.iloc[r,c])
            e1.grid(row=r,column=c,padx=5,pady=5)

    Exitbutton=Button(top,text="EXIT",fg="red",bd=5, width=10, height=10,command=root.quit)
    Exitbutton.pack(in_=top, side=LEFT)

showbutton=Button(Frame1,text="Show Data",fg="red",bd=5, width=10, height=10,command=showdata)
showbutton.pack(in_=Frame1, side=LEFT)
#showbutton.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)

Exitbutton=Button(Frame1,text="EXIT",fg="red",bd=5, width=10, height=10,command=root.quit)
Exitbutton.pack(in_=Frame1, side=LEFT)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `for r in range(start, start+40):` or `df2 = df[start:start+40]`

Comment: see [pandastable](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable)